# Syntax Problems in Rails Task command and Environment choice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

While running a task in crons.rake I got this error:

```
SyntaxError: /var/www/xyz/lib/tasks/crons.rake:12: syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting ')'
task (:clean_database => :environment) do
```

Don't understand this because I have lots of other tasks in this file with no error ...

Second Question is I want that this task is running in dev and in production mode, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use parenthesis:

```
task :clean_database => :environment do
```

or

```
task clean_database: :environment do
```

if you absolutely must (:)) use parenthesis, never put space between method and them:

```
task(clean_database: :environment) do
```

Because if you put space, Ruby interprets the content of the parenthesis not as method arguments, but as an expression. And this expression

```
(:clean_database => :environment)
```

doesn't make sense to it.

Comment: @Felix well you can, but you should not put space between method call and parenthesis. Ruby doesn't interpret this as method arguments, but as an expression - and `(:clean_database => :environment)` expression doesn't make sense. That's why you get syntax error.